# Create a link with a page number label, that will change if page number changes

Tags: visio

I added automatic page number to my Visio file with this button:
[image]
Then I created a link to another page like so:
[[image]
When I switch the page I'm linking to like that:
[image] -> [image]
The page number of `page_test2` changes from `Seite2` to `Seite3` (which is good)
But I also want my link text to change from `Link to Page 2` to `Link to Page 3`
How do I do this?
I'm using Visio 2013

Comment: How you do add automatic page number ?

Comment: I updated my question (the beginning) - does it help? I just clicked that thing and it added all page numbers automatically

Comment: when you use this way, visio application engine add to you document new backgound pages for each foreground pages !

Comment: yes, I know - but I don't know how I can link a text to always show the current number of a different page.

Comment: @Surrogate I rewrote my question to make it more understandable - if there still are questions let me know :)

Comment: Can you describe main purpose use these hyperlinks ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151602/discussion-between-surrogate-and-cold-class).